# LT6105 Current Sense Amplifier Output Problem

Tags: amplifier, analog, current-measurement

I am using the LT6105 current sense amplifier [Link](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6105fa.pdf). I am giving it a supply(Vcc) of 7V and the voltage to the Rsense is 5V. The Rin = 100Ohms and Rout = 4.7K.

The schematic is -
[image: Circuit]

Now, based on the Vout formula, it should be 1.18V if the current through R13 is 1.19A. But, I am getting Vout of 5.52V.

Now, if the load is removed I am still getting Vout of 5.52V.

Am I missing something here as the parameters are all fine for Rin and Rout.

Comment: Which side of the sense resistor is the load?

Comment: It is on the In- side. The load is supplied by 5V0

Comment: Are you sure the GND is connected to pin 4. That output voltage is probably what you would get if the chip is floating.

Comment: How can u say that its the voltage when chip is floating please ?

Comment: @Icy: The pinout looks correct, but I was about to mention that connectivity (or lack thereof) is the most likely culprit.

Comment: I understood the point. But how can you say that Vout would be 5.52V(the number I gave). Just a curiosity please.

Comment: If your output is driving into another device - e.g. an A2D input that is supplied from 5V it will typically clamp at a diode drop above the 5V level. But its really just a hunch,

Comment: OK. Anyways my output pin 5 is not connected to anything.

Comment: But all said and done, my math is correct,right ?

Comment: If pin 5 is not connected to anything that is the problem. It is an open collector output and must drive into a resistor as shown in your schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the LT6105 commercial package, or are you actually using the rad-hard MS Kennedy version as your red text shows there?

You might have been an assembly issue of some type, or your resistors aren't the values they say they are on the schematic -- I've used this part before and your circuit looks correct, and your math checks out.

Also, the load is on the -IN side, correct? I.E. 5V0_Prelim -> R13 -> 5V0 -> Load? Your first comment states the load is "powered by 5V0" which is a little ambiguous.

Side notes:

- it's good practice to put all the pins on a package on your symbol, and label them as NC + No ERC marker in the schematic
- additionally, it's a good idea to match the pin names from the manufacturer datasheet
- not a bad idea to give the part a decoupling cap or two (0.1uF/0.01uF), or run it through a ferrite or 10R resistor if it's sitting on a noisy 7V0 rail